# Is it possible to run a GUI app in Docker on Windows?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to run a Windows GUI app in Docker on Windows?

The scenario would be that you don't want to directly install an app because of global changes it is likely to make to your system; so instead run it in a Docker container. But of course you would still want to interact with it normally via display, keyboard, etc. and probably give it access to your filesystem.

Though I've found some forum posts, etc. they tend to be Linux-specific and have details about X-server, VNC, and so on which are not applicable to running Docker on Windows. I'm not interested in running Linux apps on Windows.

Comment: But Docker on Windows is (generally) still using Linux. So those things you found are very relevant.

Comment: @DanielB but not relevant to running Windows GUI apps